# Scanning file from user input

Tags: java

It has been a long time since I messed with files. I am trying to take a txt file I make in eclipse and use it in this code. The code to handle getting file name, finding file, and scanning it is:

```
System.out.println("Input from a file");
System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
String str = expression.nextLine();
int i = 0;
File file = new File(str);
Scanner fScan = new Scanner(file);
```

All I get are `FileNotFoundExceptions`. My file is in the same exact folder that all my classes for this program are in. I can't find an actual helpful answer online either .

So if someone could point out where I am going wrong that would be great :)

Comment: Please share the project structure.

Comment: I believe your input file path is wrong. Because, I got no problem

Answer (score 0):

all of these lines of code you are having should be inside a try{} and outside have a catch, that would catch the fileNotFoundException, for example,

```
Try{
/*your code here*/
// but try this
Scanner scannerName = new Scanner("FileName.<extension>"); //extension being .txt, etc
String str;
while(scannerName.hasNext());{
str = scannerName.nextLine();
/*work with str here*/
}
Catch(FileNotFoundException e){
System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file in the same package where is the class file then you can try this one also:

```
Scanner fScan = new Scanner(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt"));
//do not forget to close the Scanner in the end
fScan.close()
```

OR

Looking a file `abc.txt` from resources folder

```
File file = new File("resources/abc.txt");
```

Here is the project structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the file is in the root folder ? The default working directory, is the project directory.

If you are sure that your file is there then it's either your mistaken when typing the name of your file, or somethine else is happening, to figure it out, I suggest you to try the following 3 tests :

1-make sure when you type the name of the file there is no mistake

2-Try to put the full path of the file and see if now it will find it

3-Try to put as name something like

> new File("src/pa/Yourinput.txt").